# How to check for a local Drawable, and lacking one, how to make one from a remote resource?

Tags: android, sqlite, drawable, http-streaming

I need to take a given drawable name from a cloud DB and check to see if a matching Drawable exists in the local package.  If it doesn't, I need to create a local copy of the image for use so I'm not constantly accessing the remote resource.  What's the best way to do this? I can access the database, do the SQL, all that stuff.  I just need to know how to A) check the local package for the existence of a Drawable called (for instance) 'icon,' and if it doesn't exist locally I need to know how to create and store a local copy (via HTTPstream maybe?).

Comment: You have two questions there. And [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: My apologies for the two questions, and I haven't tried anything since I don't know where to begin.  Going to try the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1: Check for your drawable like this:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", "your.package.namespace");
if (resId == 0){
    //drawable isn't there. You have to fetch it through Http or whatever
} else {
    //getDrawable like this
    Drawable d = getResources.getDrawable(resId);
}
```

2: You can't put a downloaded drawable inside drawableFolder. But you can download it to res/raw or to the sdcard. Note to check that location also if you already downloaded this particular drawable.

Comment: Great! Found the rest of the answer elsewhere.  Thanks very much!